# How to disable field overlays of particles in Blender 2.8?

Tags: particles, 3d-view

[image]

It is quite distracting to have the fields of each particle in the view port.

I don't want to disable all the overlays in the viewport, I just want the fields of the particles to be gone.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the properties bar, under data, there is a display option which gives you the option of changing the size of the field outline.  You can set it down as far as .01, which is almost invisible.  It will at least make it far less annoying.

[image]

I found this using version 2.79, but hopefully that option is still available in 2.8